# eCharts: markLine label offset/spacing from line

Tags: echarts

The eCharts documentation doesn't seem to indicate any way to control the amount of spacing between the markLine and its label. Label position only offers "start", "middle", and "end"... Is there any way around this?

Comment: Try with a number for the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option label spacing relative to markline is to use the label padding attribute. Padding can be passed in as an array: `[top, right, bottom, left]`. Use this to control the space between the label and the markline.

Answer (score 0):

```
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line',
        markLine:{
            data:[{
                xAxis:'Tue',
                label:{
                    distance:30
                }
            }]
        }
    }]
};
```

Use the distance property inside label to adjust the spacing between the markline and the label.